# Connect to mysql container using Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, docker

I succesfully created docker with commad

> docker run --name my-db -d -p 3306:3306 -v
>   /e/DockerData/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=null" mysql

Just to test if I would have to type String 'null' as password ;)
It worked. Using

> docker exec -it my-db bash

and then

> mysql -p

i could connect to mysql command line. However when I tried to run it via workbench it did not work. I deleted both workbench and whole MySql stuff from my computer, as it could couse problems. And then I reinstalled only Workbench.
It did not help.

I was connecting via urls 0.0.0.0:3306, localhost:3306 and 192.168.99.100:3306 non of them worked. (I am working on DockerToolbox, because of Windows 10 Home).
 When I Try to connect I get this exception: 
[image]

What is also interesting is that if I stop and delete the image, and create container using:

> docker run --name my-db -p 3306:3306 -v
>   /e/DockerData/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -e
>   MYSQL_DATABASE=testDB -d mysql

I still need to use password 'null' when entering docker exec -it my-db bash  and then mysql -p
 and I have no idea what is going one.
[image]
[image]

Anyone have any idea?
​Maybe catches? Or it is stored somewhere? I removed image, pulled it again and it did not helped. Typing null as password helps, admin does not mach.

Logs:

```
$ docker logs -f 132646ed8949
2018-06-13T17:53:31.961392Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2018-06-13T17:53:31.961823Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.11) starting as process 1
mbind: Operation not permitted
2018-06-13T17:53:32.728416Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2018-06-13T17:53:32.747107Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2018-06-13T17:53:32.782912Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.infoschema@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-06-13T17:53:32.783958Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-06-13T17:53:32.784429Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-06-13T17:53:32.785231Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010315] [Server] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-06-13T17:53:32.786186Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'performance_schema mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-06-13T17:53:32.786320Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010323] [Server] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-06-13T17:53:32.786380Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010311] [Server] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-06-13T17:53:32.798621Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'user mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-06-13T17:53:32.799734Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010330] [Server] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2018-06-13T17:53:32.811232Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.11'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

​
​I removed Container and Image. Pulled it one more time, run docker Command. First try was password admin second null…
Maybe it is because the first command I run had " "     -e="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=null" ?

[image]

Comment: Try to connect to 127.0.0.1 I use this on Mac with SequelPro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, and I hope it will help someone:

It that MySQL changing their authentication style after relese 8.0
Running older versions solve the problem:

```
docker run --name my-db -p 3306:3306 -v
/e/DockerData/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -e
MYSQL_DATABASE=testDB -d mysql:5.7.22
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DB it isn't listening on any of the addresses you've provided, it is listening on the container name as from the picture you have posted.

You either can add the container hostname into your hosts files, such as: 1326xxxxxx 192.168.99.100 (which i presume it is the host ip address that you run the container on) or you could pass --***hostname*** mydb at the runtime of the container and add that into your hosts file.

Comment: docker run --name my-db -p 3306:3306 -v /e/DockerData/mysql:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin -e MYSQL_DATA
BASE=testDB --hostname 192.168.99.100 -d mysql

Yes, container runs on 192.168.99.100:3306 (Port is published as we can see in the command)
I added hostname and it appear on the docker env. However I still cannot connect.
Also I dont get, why i still need to enter 'null' for mysql password

Comment: @Thamiar have you tried a different password instead of null at the start of the container and then tried to connect using that password?